# c# path to icon in ressources

Tags: c#, toolbox

does anybody know how i can change external icon-paths into embedded resource icons?

Example: i want to change the icon of my ToolBoxItem. I have only the possibility to set the path to the icon. Setting the picture directly does not work:

```
new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof (MyItem9), "C:\\tmp\\item9.ico", "Item9"),
```

I want to change this path to the path of a embedded resource file:

```
new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof (MyItem9), "MyAssembly.Resources.myIcon.ico", "Item9"),
```

Is there any possibility to do this? Or is there even a possibility to set the icon directly?

Thanks,
el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure it out how to solve this so i made a "dirty" workaround: I saved the icons in the temp folder and referenced them in this place. This works but it is not a very clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change the signature of the hard-coded parameter(2nd one) that excepts file path in

```
new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof (MyItem9), "C:\\tmp\\item9.ico", "Item9"),
```

you can not except the same result with this code.

```
ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof (MyItem9), "MyAssembly.Resources.myIcon.ico", "Item9"),
```

But you can do following,
Create an overload of constructir of `ToolboxItemWrapper` like

```
public class ToolboxItemWrapper
{
    public ToolboxItemWrapper(Type t,Image img, string prop)
    {
        /*Do setup as in*/

    }
}
```

Later you could actually do ,

```
 new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof (MyItem9), Properties.Resources.YourImage, "Item9"),
```

Comment: unfortunately the ToolboxItemWrapper is a micosoft constructed class. I knew that the second code would not work. This is wyh i asked this question. Do you know another solution for my problem?

Comment: Ahh, My bad, it's even sealed.

Answer (score 0):

Whups, misread your post. You can't set the Icon directly, only from path

```
string res = "MyAssembly.Resources.myIcon.ico";
Stream s = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream( res );
Icon icon = Icon.FromStream( s );
```

Comment: oh... i think thats my fault. My explanation is not very good. In the end i want the path to the resource icon. Otherwise i could set the icon directly. Thanks anyway.